# Remove characters from recordset permanently

Tags: replace

I have some data in this format:

```
52-681-Functional-EHT
53-682-Functional-EGT
52-683-Functional-EZT
51-684-Functional-EYT
59-685-Functional-E5T
```

And I want to remove the interior '-Functional' *permanently* with a sql statement so that my records would now look like...

```
52-681-EHT
53-682-EGT
52-683-EZT
51-684-EYT
59-685-E5T
```

All my research leads me to `Replace` but that seems to just be on a `select` and can't quite figure out how to form it into an appropriate `update` statement. Again, I want to remove the string **FOREVER**.

[image]

**Creation script:**

```
create table part (
id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Partname nvarchar(50))

insert into Part (Partname)
values ('52-681-Functional-EHT'),
('53-682-Functional-EGT'),
('52-683-Functional-EZT'),
('51-684-Functional-EYT'),
('59-685-Functional-E5T')
```

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9e6b85a98dadb51a193334e8d8d69672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason this simple update doesn't work for you?

```
update part set partname = replace(partname,'functional-','')

select * from part
```

Comment: And... now I'm embarrassed.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `REPLACE` in an `UPDATE` is fairly straightforward. In your case, you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE p
SET Partname = REPLACE(Partname,'-Functional','')
FROM #part p;
```

However, there are always different ways to solve the same problem. You could also handle the update by using `SUBSTRING` to build the desired value based on character position:

```
UPDATE p
SET Partname = SUBSTRING(Partname,1,6) + SUBSTRING(Partname,18,4)
FROM #part p;
```